Vert.x scala-lang boostrap
I started try the Verticle bootstrap for Scala, ran the instructions and I've got the following issue in sbt:
[IJ]~reStart
[info] sbt server started at local:///Users/ronaldo/.sbt/1.0/server/7f116dd39f5d583bb287/sock
[info] started sbt server
[info] compiling 2 Scala sources to /Users/ronaldo/BRVRTec/vertx/vertex-scala-verticles/target/scala-3.5.0/classes ...
[warn] bad option '-target:17' was ignored
[warn] one warning found
[info] done compiling
[info] Application root not yet started
[info] Starting application root in the background ...
root Starting io.vertx.core.Launcher.main(run, scala:vertx.scala.myapp.HttpVerticle)
[success] Total time: 6 s, completed 2024 Oct 28 16:22:55
[info] 1. Monitoring source files for root/reStart...
[info]    Press <enter> to interrupt or '?' for more options.
root[ERROR] Error: Could not find or load main class io.vertx.core.Launcher
root[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.vertx.core.Launcher
root ... finished with exit code 1

I found that class in project/Build.scala but still I'm not sure what is the source of the Error.
Can anyone tell me how to correctly insert io.vertx.core.Launcher
I tried to add
import io.vertx.core.Launcher to Build.scala but it didn't work.
[Update] this is the generated code from `sbt new vert-x3/vertx-scala.g8``
vertx/scala/myapp/HttpVerticle.scala
package vertx.scala.myapp

import io.vertx.lang.scala.ScalaVerticle
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router
import io.vertx.lang.scala.ImplicitConversions.vertxFutureToScalaFuture

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.language.implicitConversions

class HttpVerticle extends ScalaVerticle:

  override def asyncStart: Future[Unit] =
    // Create a router to answer GET-requests to "/hello" with "world"
    val router = Router.router(vertx)
    router.get("/hello").handler(_.response.end("world"))

    vertx
      .createHttpServer()
      .requestHandler(router)
      .listen(8666, "0.0.0.0")
      .mapEmpty[Unit]()

vertx/scala/myapp/BusVerticle.scala
package vertx.scala.myapp

import io.vertx.lang.scala.ScalaVerticle
import scala.concurrent.Future

class BusVerticle extends ScalaVerticle:

  override def asyncStart: Future[Unit] =
    vertx
      .eventBus
      .consumer[String]("testAddress")
      .handler(_.reply("Hello World!"))
    Future.successful(())

The resource io.vertx.core.Launcher is mentioned in project/Build.scala
import sbt.{Def, _}
import sbtassembly.AssemblyPlugin.autoImport.*
import sbtassembly.{AssemblyPlugin, PathList}
import Keys._
import spray.revolver.RevolverPlugin
import spray.revolver.RevolverPlugin.autoImport.reStartArgs
import de.gccc.jib.JibPlugin
import de.gccc.jib.JibPlugin.autoImport.*
import java.util.jar.Attributes.Name

object Build extends AutoPlugin {

  object autoImport {
    val vertxBuild = taskKey[Seq[String]]("Builds a Vert.x Scala project")
    val mainVerticle = settingKey[String]("Canonical class name of the main Verticle")
  }

  override def trigger = allRequirements

  override def requires: Plugins = AssemblyPlugin && RevolverPlugin && JibPlugin

  /**
    * Start arguments for the application. This is basically the `run` command for the
    * Vert.x Launcher and the qualified class name of the main Verticle.
    */
  private def startArgs(mainVerticleFqcn: String): List[String] = List("run", s"scala:${mainVerticleFqcn}")

  import autoImport.*
  override def projectSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = 
    Vector(
      // Compilation settings
      scalacOptions ++= Vector(
        "-unchecked",
        "-deprecation",
        "-target:17",
        "-encoding", "UTF-8"
      ),
      Compile / mainClass := Some("io.vertx.core.Launcher"),
      Compile / packageOptions += {
        Package.ManifestAttributes(new Name("Main-Verticle") -> s"scala:${mainVerticle.value}")
      },

      // SBT revolver plugin settings
      reStartArgs := startArgs(mainVerticle.value),

      // Settings for single jar assembly with the assembly plugin
      assembly / assemblyJarName := "vertex-scala-verticles.jar",
      assembly / assemblyMergeStrategy := {
        case PathList("META-INF", "MANIFEST.MF")                  => MergeStrategy.discard
        case PathList("META-INF", xs@_*)                          => MergeStrategy.last
        case PathList("META-INF", "io.netty.versions.properties") => MergeStrategy.last
        case "module-info.class"                                  => MergeStrategy.discard
        case "org/apache/commons/jexl3/internal/MapBuilder.class" => MergeStrategy.last
        case x                                                    => assemblyMergeStrategy.value(x)
      },

      // Settings for Docker image building with the jib plugin
      jibTcpPorts := List(8666),
      jibBaseImage := "eclipse-temurin:17.0.6_10-jre-alpine",
      jibJvmFlags := List("-noverify", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom"),
      jibUseCurrentTimestamp := true,
      jibArgs := startArgs(mainVerticle.value)
    )

}


Could you provide a minimal reproducible example?

project/Build.scala is for what is called the "meta project" or "meta build". The dependency to Vertex should be in the build.sbt file. This is just a wild guess ; as Gaston said, please provide more details.

Hello both. Thanks for replying.
Actually it is just the seed from sbt new vert-x3/vertx-scala.g8
I'll update the body of the question with the generated code.
